# What is a "post notice" or "notice on answer"?

Tags: discussion, moderation, post-notices

A message appeared in my Inbox informing me that . . . a notice had been attached to one of my accepted answers.  The notice seems to me a comment from a moderator, but as far as I can tell the author is anonymous (I could not read the notice/comment on the mobile App, I had to login using a browser to display the full contents).

I searched through the Help, as well as the Biology Meta posts but could not find any description of these notices.

Is this mechanism documented anywhere? In particular is there a way for me to respond/reply?

Answer (score 5):

These are canned messages that are available to mods. They are:

[image: mod notices]

You can see who added it by checking the [edit history](https://biology.stackexchange.com/posts/31493/revisions) of your answer. In this case, you will see that a notice was added by @WYSIWIG.

Once you have addressed the issue raised by the notice, you can leave a comment, notifying @WYSIWIG and he can remove it.

Answer (score 3):

**Post notice** is a very docile feature which a moderator can use to mark an answer. There are three types of post-notices:

1. Current event: Marks the answer as one that may not be useful in future.
2. Insufficient explanation: Marks the answer to be insufficient in content
3. Citation needed

These are pretty useless actually (mostly a fancy, templated comment) but can sometimes be used to mark a highly voted/accepted answer which seemingly has one of the above issues, while letting the post remain. Sometimes IMO it can be used as a disclaimer. I don't know about its historical usage in StackOverflow.