# How do you link questions to previous answers?

Tags: support

Can someone tell me how you link or redirect a question to a previous answer? I'm still trying to figure all this out and would appreciate a hand. Thanks!

Comment: You simply add the link?!

Comment: You mean just paste the link into the answer ?

Comment: Yes. There is an option called "share", below the post. Click on that and you will get a link to the post (question or answer). You can copy that link and paste in your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can copy the link from the "*share*" button found under every question or answer. Then you can either paste the html link directly into your question (which will be shown as the question title) or link through a text string (sometimes a bit more readable).

Examples using the second most recent meta post (remove single space in html links to make them functional):

> http:// meta.biology.stackexchange.com/q/3228/3624
>   [See this question](http:// meta.biology.stackexchange.com/q/3228/3624)

Result:

> [What is a "post notice" or "notice on answer"?](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3228/3624)
>   [See this question](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3228/3624)

Note that direct html links are not displayed as question titles when included in comments (the actual address is shown instead), so I prefer linking through a text string there, to clearly show what the link is leading to.