# Feature Request: Modification to the "citations needed" banner

Tags: feature-request, answers, references

Following an upvoted answer on [this question](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3282/functionality-request-community-voting-for-answers-citations-need-banner), I'm reposting as a feature request.

---

**I think the "citations needed" banner is too ineffectual (see examples in [this post](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3345/an-effective-measure-to-counter-unreferenced-answers)) in its current form, and should;**

*i)* Be more strongly worded<sup>*</sup>

*ii)* Answers with the banner should be faded out (the same as highly downvoted answers) to highlight to other users that there are issues with the answer before they read it.

*iii)* Anyone who (up)votes on a banner-marked answer should get a pop-up notification that they should reconsider voting given that the answer falls short on some of the standards set by Biology SE.

---

**Current Banner**

> Some of the information contained in this post requires additional references. Please edit to add citations to reliable sources that support the assertions made here. Unsourced material may be disputed or deleted.

---

<sup>*</sup>**Proposed text**

> Some of the information contained in this post requires additional references. Please edit to add citations to reliable sources that support the assertions made here. Unreferenced answers may not be reliable, and are often highlited because they present opinions as fact, make disputed claims, or contain information that may be incorrect, and **should be read with caution as a result.**

Answer (score 2):

[Post-notices](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3228/what-is-a-post-notice-or-notice-on-answer) are basically templated comments that come with a box. They can be posted only by moderators. There are no custom post-notices. If you want a change in the statement then it has to be implemented throughout the SE network. Such feature requests are supposed to be posted in http://meta.stackexchange.com. However, the developers would consider your request only if it is really needed (for all SE sites), which I don't think is the case.

Therefore, you can convey your thoughts about the answer through a comment.